# Including option descriptions for a Google Docs Spreadsheet form

Tags: google-sheets

Usually, the options for a form are pretty self-intuitive, but sometimes, you need to explain each of the individual options. In close proximity to the actual question. However, the options for a Google Docs form aren't very conducive to a good illustration. Below is an image of a troublesome section of our form in the [Gaming Promotional Grant](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/gaming-promotional-grant-round-7).

[image: Form has a huge wordy and run-on description]

There are two general options on a form to explain these things, but the way the form is created appears to not be conducive towards this kind of explanation.

- You can include the short description of each option in the Description at the top. Usually using *linebreaks* to separate each option for readability. It does not appear, through basic testing, that linebreaks are permitted.
- You can include the short description of each option in each radio button. This makes the form look shiny, but then the resulting spreadsheet is an *absolute monster* because the cell will be filled with the complete text. It makes reading through the table a complete pain.

To that end, I'm wondering if either of the two is possible, if not some other alternative option that would allow me to include readable descriptions of options on a radio button selection:

- Is there any way to include linebreaks in the help text for a form field?
- Is there a way to separate the "value" of a radio button from its "text", so that the button's label will include the text description, but the stored value (and hence the cell in the spreadsheet) will not?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your only choice is rephrasing so that the right answer is obvious:

> #### What would you like to get the game from?
>
> *This affects the way we reimburse you. If you'd like to get the game through Steam, we'll simply gift it to you. If you'd like to get the game through Amazon, we'll try and get you a gift card for the same amount of money. Otherwise, you'll need to send us a scan of the receipt and we'll reimburse you through PayPal and Moneybookers.*
>
> ( ) Steam
> ( ) Amazon
> ( ) Other